# Formatting grid UTM coordinate numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, expression, format

In QGIS 3.16 I have used the expression:

```
@grid_number || if(@grid_axis='x', ' mE', ' mN')
```

to add the suffix "mE" and "mN" to the UTM grid labels in a layout window (e.g "550000 mE").

How do I add a comma separator for the thousands in the labels (e.g. convert "550000 mE" to "550,000 mE")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you store the label in a `"label"` field in the attribute table, try:

```
to_string(format_number(regexp_substr("label", '(\\d+)'),0)) || regexp_substr("label", '(\\s.*$)')
```

[image]

Change the field name `"label"` according to your data.

Note:

`(1) to_string(format_number(regexp_substr("label", '(\\d+)'),0))`
takes number (e.g. 550000) and add comma to it.

`(2) regexp_substr("label", '(\\s.*$)')` extracts  `mW` or  `mN` (a space and the following texts till the end of the string).

---

**UPDATE** To make it work within the **Layout** using `@grid_number`, try:

`format_number(to_int(@grid_number),0) ||if(@grid_axis='x',' mE',' mN')`

You just need to convert the `@grid_number` to a numeric number (e.g. integer) before applying `format_number()`.

Comment: To clarify, the labels are generated in the Layout from the "Grids" item. The data is not stored in an attribute table. Under "Map Grid Properties" "Draw Coordinates" section I chose "Custom" for the Format and used @grid_number ||if(@grid_axis='x',' mE',' mN') to get the suffix. I have not been successful in using the format_number command.

Comment: @PeterCaristo Ah, then it's easy. `format_number( to_int(@grid_number),0) ||if(@grid_axis='x',' mE',' mN')`. You just need to convert `@grid_number` to number (integer) before applying `format_number()`

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly. Thanks @Kazuhito